# How scheduler talks to API server?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to know, in which parts of the codes in kubernetes (
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes) the scheduler talks to the API server and then the API server sends out the scheduling information to kubelet?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please explain why you need it -or- what you are trying to do? it would be helpful for other users to understand & get some response quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduler register a informer to specify resource(e.g. pod, PV...), register some callback function to event(e.g. add, delete, update...), these code at: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/scheduler/eventhandlers.go#L319.

Then event callback will put pod spec in the [queue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/scheduler/internal/queue/scheduling_queue.go), scheduler will check the queue, add use some [algorithm](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/scheduler_interface.go) to schedule the pod to some node. Finally, scheduler will update the pod information to apiserver.

Kubelet will check the apiserver to find which pod need update, then create the container, bind the volume...

p.s. It is complex to understand the whole lifecycle about how kubernetes works, please provide what you want to know exactly.